# Facebook Connect blank page

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I have a strange problem with Facebook Connect on one of my sites. It was working perfectly before this morning. I've checked all recent changes, and nothing seems to be related with this issue.

Note: I'm using FBML, and deleting cookies for my site and for Facebook with each test.

When I click the Facebook Connect Button, the login form appears correctly. The blank page occurs when Facebook checks the permissions at this URL:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?[list of params...]

I have no Javascript errors, and no HTML is returned.

I tried to set the wanted permissions to perms="email" only, in case where the permissions changed in the pasts days, but I have the same problem.

Does anyone has a clue about this situation?

Comment: Why are you using *FBML*? Please run your test with a network sniffer, or developers tools with a network tab active, check the response from the request that ended with a blank page, what's the status code and so on.

Comment: I strongly recommend you stop using FBML immediately; the FBML endpoints will be removed in 5 weeks' time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were already scheduled to remove all FBML tags on this site, and replacing it with JS corrected the issue we had !

So the Facebook Connect using FBML seems no longer supported, even if it's supposed to be.

Comment: I have same issue but no FBML whatsoever.